# Finding element using CSS Selector/Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, css-selectors

My code goes to a website, clicks each iteration of row (of the table) which opens a new window.

I want to scrape 1 information per this new window, but I am having difficulty using CSS selectors to get this field (**Faculty**)

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
productlink=[]
driver.get('https://aaaai.planion.com/Web.User/SearchSessions?ACCOUNT=AAAAI&CONF=AM2021&USERPID=PUBLIC&ssoOverride=OFF')
time.sleep(3)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
productlist=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('clickdiv')

for item in productlist:
    item.click() #opens the new window per each row
    time.sleep(2)
    faculty=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b')
    print(faculty)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('XX').click()#closes window
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Why do you need CSS selector? Xpath is fine. You got the element, just print(faculty.text).

Comment: No, he cant do it. Faculty is an array, he cant print the text attribute. The only form is do a for and print the .text of all the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
 faculty=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b')
```

So you have an array of elements; when you print, you will have something like differents selenium elements. If you only have one element, you can use find_element_by_xpath instead of find_elements_by_xpath.

If you want to obtain the faculty values, and you have an array, you need to do a for and extract the text or get the attribute of all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Faculty reside within a table with class `sorttable`. You want the first of these so can use `nth-of-type` to restrict matches. Then the actual names are within b tags so use a child combinator ( )to move to the child `b` tags within the table. Use a list comprehension to return a faculty list:

```
faculty = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sortable:nth-of-type(1) b')
```

Comment: Went to see if you had any outstanding clinical trials questions but only found this. Clinical trials are interesting in terms of data.